# Compare with time part only in mongodb query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Below is my mongo document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b62b70a9d08f201646a9a96"),
    "name" : "but",
    "startTime" : ISODate("2018-11-17T13:15:25.000Z"),
    "status" : "completed"
}
```

I have below mongo query

```
let startTime = moment().toDate()
let endTime = moment().add(30, 'minutes').toDate()

await Workout.find({ startTime: { $gte: startTime, $lte: endTime } })
```

I need to compare with the time part only for the `startTime` field i.e. for `13:15:25`. Which means every day at that time I can retrieve that document.

How can I search with the only time part?

**Thank you!!!**

Comment: It's not really practical with a BSON Date and you're not the first to ask. The better solution if you don't care about the date part for queries is to simply store the time. Depending on how accurate you actually need to be, something like "milliseconds since start of day" is usually sufficient for most cases. If you don't need that granular you can use a smaller numeric format.

Comment: Only really adding the duplicate with the aggregate sample since others would only copy or propose the same result. It's not really the correct approach since such calculation is very costly. Better to update your data with "just time" values instead.

Comment: Will this be better to use aggregation here. Something like `db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      date: {
        $dateFromParts: {
          "year": 2017,
          "month": 14,
          "day": 1,
          "hour": {
            $hour: "$startTime"
          },
          "minute": {
            $minute: "$startTime"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $match: { ... }}
])` ??

Comment: No. Look at the linked duplicate. There are answers there, as well as a new one with a better explanation why aggregation is wrong here.

Comment: Great answer @NeilLunn. I am going with that. Just want to know `16 * 60 * 60 * 1000` is this 24 hour format? Can I get this using `moment()`?

Comment: Well the original question used 24 hours so it's being consistent. 1600 is of course 4:00pm. But you should base on 24 hour format whatever you do. And there are functions in momentJS which return milliseconds for a time of day, yes.